# VLC can play RTMP but jwplayer can't

Tags: stream, vlc, jwplayer, rtmp

This is a rtmp server from a site like twitch.tv

So I got the link of rtmp, VLC can play it very well but when I use jwplayer, it said

```
"ERROR LOADING STREAM: CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER"
```

But the website using jwplayer and still working.

I give you some link for test:

```
rtmp://live.csmtalk.vcdn.vn/livetv?ak=/themmsstudio
rtmp://live.csmtalk.vcdn.vn/livetv?ak=/pewpewvn
rtmp://live.csmtalk.vcdn.vn/livetv?ak=/virussssssser
```

Comment: Is it possible that this stream has some restrictions set on it as to where it can be played from?

Comment: I dont know, that why I am asking!

Comment: I am not sure either. This stream seems like it might be secureed though.

Comment: Any way to do it? you can try now with this url : rtmp://live.csmtalk.vcdn.vn/livetv?ak=/pewpewvn

Comment: Same error. I am not sure what server they are using, but I am sure they would not want their bandwidth to be taken, though.

Comment: Use Wireshark to look at the initial packets. Chances are that some parameters are sent when you use jwplayer, which are missing when you use VLC.